# What would happen if a linked list was implemented without pointers?

Tags: c, linked-list

The standard struct for list node is:

```
struct node {
  int x;
  struct node *next;
};
```

But, what would happen if we defined a node without a pointer, like this:

```
struct node {
      int x;
      struct node next;
};
```

?

I assume that the main problem would be not knowing where the list ends, since there wouldn't be a `NULL` pointer. But apart from that is there any other effects to be taken into consideration?

Comment: It would not be a linked list?

Comment: To understand infinite descent, you must first understand infinite descent.

Comment: Have you tried to compile the above declaration? What do you think should be the size of a structure defined that way?

Comment: @odin what do you think the compiler would do with `sizeof(struct node)`?

Comment: @David Heffernan Ok then, but can you how `sizeof(struct node*)` is calculated? Why isn't that recursive as well?

Comment: @odin19: The size of pointer types is independent of the size of the type they point to.

Comment: A data pointer can be represented as a memory address, so its size is guaranteed to be the same regardless of type it points to. (This does not necessarily apply to function pointers.)

Comment: @user4815162342: Actually, pointers to different object types *may* have different sizes and representations - see the [online C11 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), section 6.2.5, para 28.  On systems like x86 you can count on them being the same size, but be aware it doesn't have to be the case.

Comment: @JohnBode Good point - I was thinking of the rule that data pointers must fit in a `void *`. Pointers to different kinds of data can be of different sizes, but may not be larger than the size of `void *` (which equals the size of `char *`). I wonder if there ever was an architecture that made use of this possibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A struct type may not contain an instance of itself as a member for two reasons.

First, the type definition isn't complete until the closing `}` of the struct type; until the type definition is complete, the compiler won't know how much space to allocate for that member.  Secondly, a struct type that contains an instance of itself would be infinitely large.

A struct type may contain a *pointer* to itself as a member since pointers to incomplete types are allowed, and all struct pointer types have the same size and representation.

You can create linked lists without using pointers; I did it Fortran 77, which didn't have pointer types.  You simply use an array as your storage, and use array indices as your "pointers".

Comment: if the type definition is incomplete then why isn't  the declaration `struct node* next;` erroneous?

Comment: Because pointers to incomplete types are allowed; the compiler doesn't need to know the size of the pointed-to type in order to create a pointer to it.

Answer (score 2):

> What would happen if we defined a node without a pointer, like this:
>
> ```
> struct node {
>     int x;
>     struct node next;
> };
> ```

This declares a structure with unterminated recursion. Hence the declaration is invalid and is rejected by the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Let's calculate this:

```
sizeof(struct node)
```

Well, we have an `int`, possibly some padding and `sizeof(struct node)`. Putting it into one formula:

```
sizeof(struct node) = sizeof(int) + padding + sizeof(struct node)
```

This cannot be solved.

Thinking about it less theoretically, it would be a structure containing an infinite number of itself.

Languages that don't have value semantics but use reference semantics instead, like Haskell, allow this kind of data structures (types). I'm oversimplifying a lot here, but think of every structure member (record field) as a pointer, then it's probably clear why or works there:

```
data List = EndOfList | Node Int List
```